# How to pass array from gulp to other js files?

Tags: gulp

I have a gulpfile.js with a method:
gulp.task('default', function() {...}}

How can I pass data out of gulp so that I can use it in another javascript file?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another module that contains your array and require it in other javascript files:

variables.js

```
module.exports = {
    myArray : ['value1', 'value2']
}
```

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    vars = require('./variables');

    gulp.task('default', function() {
        console.log(vars.myArray);
    });
```

Comment: Sorry for making you misunderstood. I mean in an opposite way: pass data out of gulp task, and use it in another .js file.

Comment: What data do you need to pass from the gulp task to another JS file?

Comment: When uploading files through gulp-scp2 module, I want to get the file name when it is uploaded successfully. gulp-scp2 has a method named transfer, inside transfer(), it will tell me which file is uploaded successfully. The thing is to get the filename from there.

Comment: Thank you so much.